# Call related data with populated select from php database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i mange to populate the select by calling data on database
how will i call other data related from the value of the select using database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'a', 'emp_table') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select * from emp");
echo "<select name='id'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $name = $row['name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';                

}
echo "</select>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ajax for both 1. getting `emp` and related info

Comment: Have you tried anything to fetch data while changing select option? Try to read about https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp and there are thousands of resource available for this.

Comment: @Von David, You mean to say, whenever any user selects the drop-down value and related to that dropdown value you have to display the record. right?

Comment: @Von David, Have you checked my answer? is it working?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
As per @Nikhil suggested the link
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

You can achieve this using AJAX. Time to learn the AJAX now.

For connection
If you are working on the localhost the no need to require the password. It should be blank.

I just added the `onchange` function to the select tag. So whatever the user selects from the dropdown it will call the function `getRole` and pass the Id to the process page. Process page will return the value related to the ID and display in the `span` tag.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "emp_table";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <select name="emp_name" id="emp_name"  onchange="getRole(this.value);" >
    <option selected disabled>Select</option>
      <?php 
        $result = $conn->query("select * from emp"); 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $id = $row['id'];
                  $name = $row['name']; 
            ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>
        <?php }}?>
    </select>

    <span id="emp_details"></span><!--it will display the emp record from process page-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getRole(val){
       var id=$('#emp_name').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'process.php',
           type:'POST',
           data:'id='+id,
           success:function(data)
           {
            //alert(data);
              $("#emp_details").html(data);
           },

           });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   echo $country_id=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));// here you will get the id of the employee
   /*your more code here*/
}
 ?>
```